# iOS: How to set destinationViewController's image in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my `HomeController.m` controller I have this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    BlahController *dvc = (BlahController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSLog(@"%@", segue.identifier); // prints out "round"
    dvc.coolImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"round"]];
}
```

This is the 2nd controller it's supposed to push to:

```
@interface BlahController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *coolImage;

@end
```

However, this doesn't work. I'm guessing it's because the outlets are not set yet at that point? I'm not sure, but when I put the last line in the controller itself with `self.coolImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"round"]];`, it works so I know the image path is correct.

How would I set the image?

Comment: As you suspect, if you check `dvc.coolImage` in `prepareForSegue`, it will be nil.  You'll have to pass the details to a different (strong) property, then set the image after the view has loaded.

Comment: great thanks @PetahChristian

Comment: or you can call [dvc view]; to force the view controller to load it's subviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, if you check `dvc.coolImage` in `prepareForSegue`, it will be nil. You'll have to pass the details to a different (strong) property, then set the image after the view has loaded.

One unrelated tip to shorten your code:

```
... imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"round"]
```

can simply be replaced with a string literal

```
imageNamed:"round"
```

As an aside, I wouldn't encourage anyone to "game the system" by having the source view controller force the destination view controller to load its view.  Trying to compensate for or work around how the system behaves behind the scenes, makes your code more fragile.

I imagine you appreciate the reason for doing it differently, by passing your properties independently from what they'd internally be wired up to.

This lets your destination view controller be a black box.  The source shouldn't need to know that it's setting an imageView's image, or be concerned with whether a view is loaded.  It just has to provide a string.  Only the destination needs to know what to internally do with the string it's been given, when it loads itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the `UIImageView` property is not yet loaded. The solution is pretty simple - create a `UIImage` property and set it in `prepareForSegue:`, then update the `UIImageView` on `viewDidLoad`:

```
// On your source view controller
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue.destinationViewController setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"round"]];
}

// On your destination view controller
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage * image;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

-

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { BlahController *dvc = (BlahController *)segue.destinationViewController; 
dvc.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"round"]; 

}
```

In Blah.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;
```

In Blah.m viewDidLoad method

```
self.myImageView.image = self.myImage

;
```